# Webpack: Loading Codesplit Chunks from S3 Using Django Storage

Tags: django, amazon-s3, webpack, django-storage, code-splitting

I am using django storages to serve my static files from s3, and am in the process of moving them all into a webpack bundle. This works well with `django-webpack-loader` which doesn't care where django finds the bundle.

My problem is that when I start to define split points using `require.ensure`, the bundle attempts to download the chunk using a relative path, instead of the s3 bucket, because webpack's codesplitting feature is agnostic to django storage.

Is there a way to inject custom logic for fetching the chunks on demand? I'm not above hard coding my s3 bundle address into the config file, but nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Here is my webpack config (written in coffeescript)

```
path = require "path"
webpack = require 'webpack'
BundleTracker = require 'webpack-bundle-tracker'
ExtractTextPlugin = require "extract-text-webpack-plugin"
loaders = require "./loaders.coffee"

module.exports =
    context: __dirname
    entry: require "./entries.coffee"
    output:
        path: path.resolve 'app/static/dist/'
        filename: '[name].js'
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].map.js",
    devtool: "source-map"

        plugins: [

            new BundleTracker filename: './webpack/webpack-stats-prod.json'

            new webpack.DefinePlugin
            'process.env':
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify 'production'

            new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin

            new ExtractTextPlugin "[name].css"

            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin
            sourceMap: false
            compressor:
                warnings: false


        ]

    module:
        loaders: loaders.production_loaders

    resolve: loaders.resolution
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I just need to set the publicPath option under `output`. I set up my ansible script to write the bucket address into a nearby file.

```
{bucket} = require "./bucket.json"


module.exports =
    context: __dirname
    entry: require "./entries.coffee"
    output:
        path: path.resolve 'app/static/dist/'
        filename: '[name].js'
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].map.js",
        publicPath: bucket + "/static/dist/"
```